# How to retrieve data from MS Access?

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I'm new to using Database in java.

I would like to know how to retrieve data from MS Access and display it in my java program.

Also, how can I make the scores sorted from highest to lowest since it is a game program and I want to display the high scores.

I place my code below, it is supposed to save the names and scores to an MS access database.

```
package Final;

import java.sql.*;

public class GameDatabase{

Connection connect;
Statement state;
ResultSet result;

GameDatabase(){ 
    try{    
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:GameDB");
        state = connect.createStatement();  

        addProfile();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
public void addProfile(){
    try{
        result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblScores");
        String s1="INSERT INTO tblScores(Name, Score) VALUES('"+Character.playerName+"',"+Character.score+")";
        state.executeUpdate(s1);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

}
```

Comment: Your DB url seems to be wrong "jdbc:odbc:GameDB"

Comment: can you share the error you're getting? where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong

```
state.executeUpdate(s1);
```

you should write `state.executeQuery(s1);`

`executeUpdate()` is used for inserting or updating or deleting while `executeQuery()` is used for select queries.

Comment: My code above is really for inserting names and scores in the database. I just need codes on how to retrieve those data that i inserted. thanks for the quick reply anyway. :)